# Excel: OFFSET Formula in Name Manager

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I defined names for frequently used formulas like below:

> pointer =DataSheet!$A$1
>     sh1X0 =OFFSET(DataSheet!C7,0,0,DataSheet!pointer+1,1)
>     sh1X0 =OFFSET(DataSheet!F7,0,0,DataSheet!pointer+1,1)

[image: Entered Names]

I close the Name Manager.
I am using them to make chart series. 
Everything works fine.
So far the active cell is B4.
I select a different cell, say B5, all the offset formulas are changing (getting corrupted) relative to the selected range.
The above mentioned formulas change to:

> sh1X0 =OFFSET(DataSheet!C8,0,0,DataSheet!pointer+1,1)
>       sh1X0 =OFFSET(DataSheet!F8,0,0,DataSheet!pointer+1,1)

If C5 is the selection, then

> sh1X0 =OFFSET(DataSheet!D8,0,0,DataSheet!pointer+1,1)
>     sh1X0 =OFFSET(DataSheet!G8,0,0,DataSheet!pointer+1,1)

[image: Corrupted Names]

Why are the formulas changing?
How can they be kept independent from the selection of the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, your formulas are relative. You need to make them absolute by using dollar signs, e.g.:

sh1X0 `=OFFSET(DataSheet!$C$7,0,0,DataSheet!pointer+1,1)`

Note that you can select the C7 part and hit <kbd>F4</kbd> a couple of times to get the dollar signs right.

This [Jan Karel Pieterse page](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/ExcelNames03.asp) has an explanation of absolute and relative references in defined names.